# Class object not detected as class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

So here's my full code, I've done anything like renaming it and it still does not detect my object "atm".
I'm always getting this error.

> C:\Users\USER\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\oreo\src\oreo.java:30:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>                         System.out.println("\nYour Savings balance is now: " + atm.gbalance + "\n");

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class oreo {
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account atm = new Account();

        atm.intBalance(0.00);

        boolean atm_status = true;
        while(atm_status) {
            System.out.print("1.Deposit\n");
            System.out.print("\n2.Withdraw");
            System.out.print("\n3.Check Balance");
            System.out.print("\n4.Exit");
            System.out.print("\nOption: ");
            int option = input.nextInt();

            switch(option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("How much would you like to deposit?");
                    double deposit = input.nextDouble();
                    atm.deposit(deposit);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    double withdraw;
                    System.out.print("Your balance is:" + atm.gbalance + "\n");
                    System.out.print("How much would you like to withdraw?" );
                    withdraw= input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("\nYour Savings balance is now: " + atm.gbalance + "\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Your current balance is: " + atm.gbalance + "\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    atm_status = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


class Account {
    double balance;

    void intBalance(double set) {
        balance = set;
    }

    void deposit(double depo) {
        balance +=depo;
    }

    void withdraw(double with){
        balance -=with;
    }

    double gbalance(){
        return balance;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`atm.gbalance` is a method and not a variable in your `Account` class so you need the parentheses `()` while accessing it. So change these

```
atm.gbalance
```

to

```
atm.gbalance()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting the parenthesis `()` while calling the class method `atm.gbalance`;

```
System.out.println("\nYour Savings balance is now: " + atm.gbalance() + "\n");

System.out.println("Your current balance is now: " + atm.gbalance() + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("\nYour Savings balance is now: " + atm.gbalance + "\n"
```

Well, either you wanna use the variable balance or the method `gbalance()`
`atm.gbalance` is wrong either as typo (exclude "g") or either as typo add `()` to the end to define it as a method.